# How to use apollo subscription in production

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-server, vercel, ws

I have deployed my apollo server in Zeit now 2.0. So got a https endpoint which I can use in apollo client. But my apollo-server has subscription and to use it in apollo client which requires a ws endpoint.

So any suggestion how do I get the ws endpoint from the Zeit now?

Answer (score 1):

The Zeit not yet support websocket connection. So I have shifted to heroku.